# Deserializing nested elements in JSON directly

Tags: c#, json.net, deserialization

Suppose I have following JSON:

```
{
  id: 123,
  attr: {
    info: {
      dat: [{data:1}, {data:2}]
    }
  }
}
```

is it possible to desirialize whole object but get `dat` array directly without creating nested hierarchy of `attr` and `info`?

I've tried using (naive)

```
public class DataContainer {

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "id")]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "attr.info.dat")]
    public List<dat> Data { get; set; }
}
```

but with no avail.

The other obvious solution is of course create a separate class without the hierarchy, parse JSON and then copy required data to a new object. I use this approach currently, but it would be nice if it possible to parse directly to desired structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quick way to do this is to use Json.Net's Linq-To-Json API.  Assuming your classes are defined like this:

```
public class DataContainer
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public List<Dat> Data { get; set; }
}

public class Dat
{
    public int Data { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can deserialize your JSON into your class structure like this:

```
string json = @"{
  ""id"": 123,
  ""attr"": {
    ""info"": {
      ""dat"": [{""data"":1}, {""data"":2}]
    }
  }
}";

JObject jo = JObject.Parse(json);
DataContainer container = new DataContainer();
container.ID = jo["id"].Value<int>();
container.Data = jo["attr"]["info"]["dat"].ToObject<List<Dat>>();

Console.WriteLine("id:" + container.ID);
foreach (Dat d in container.Data)
{
    Console.WriteLine(d.Data);
}
```

Output:

```
id:123
1
2
```

A slightly more robust solution is to take the above code and put it into a custom `JsonConverter` which can then be used with `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject()`.  This encapsulates the deserialization logic and makes the main code a little cleaner.  Below is the code for the converter. (Note that I implemented the `WriteJson` method also, but you don't really need this unless you want to serialize your classes back to JSON.)

```
public class DataContainerConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return (objectType == typeof(DataContainer));
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        JObject jo = JObject.Load(reader);
        DataContainer container = new DataContainer();
        container.ID = jo["id"].Value<int>();
        container.Data = jo["attr"]["info"]["dat"].ToObject<List<Dat>>(serializer);
        return container;
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        DataContainer container = (DataContainer)value;
        JObject jo = new JObject();
        jo.Add("id", container.ID);
        JObject attr = new JObject();
        jo.Add("attr", attr);
        JObject info = new JObject();
        attr.Add("info", info);
        JArray dat = JArray.FromObject(container.Data, serializer);
        info.Add("dat", dat);
        jo.WriteTo(writer);
    }
}
```

You can use the JsonConverter either by decorating your class with the `[JsonConverter]` attribute:

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(DataContainerConverter))]
public class DataContainer
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public List<Dat> Data { get; set; }
}
```

or by passing an instance of it to `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject()`:

```
var container = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataContainer>(json, new DataContainerConverter());
```

Comment: Thanks for detailed answer. I guess what summarizes my possible options, but either seems more complex than approach I currently use (simple DTO->Model converter method).

Answer (score 1):

try this

if you want to convert your Json string to a class use this http://json2csharp.com/ then follow the code ... it works fine for me

```
public class Dat
{
public int data { get; set; }
}

 public class Info
 {
  public List<Dat> dat { get; set; }
 }

public class Attr
{
 public Info info { get; set; }
}

 public class RootObject
 {
   public int id { get; set; }
  public Attr attr { get; set; }
 }



 string sValue = "{id: 123,attr: {info: {dat: [{data:1}, {data:2}]}}}";
        System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer ObjJSerializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
        var Data = ObjJSerializer.Deserialize<RootObject>(sValue);
```

Comment: Well, yes, that's exactly what I try to avoid ( *without creating nested hierarchy* part of the question).

Comment: Okie i will make a try... and will come back,.its a new task for me also :)

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the tool link, may come in handy!